# Multiple files attachment in contact form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf, contact-form

When i Exporting form results from Contact form 7 to PDF (fPDF). Then our contact form 7 file uploading is not showing in contact form 7 message body. Means at a time both attachments files are not showing properly how to fix this.i am creating a pdf using my code and then attaching that to my email that work fine but when i upload file from contact form 7 front-end then our pdf file is not showing.My code is:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_components', 'mycustom_wpcf7_mail_components' );
function mycustom_wpcf7_mail_components($components){

if (!empty($components['attachments'])) {
//$components['attachments'] = array( 'attachedfile' =>  FPDF_PATH.'/dompdf-master/'.'Shoop.pdf'); // ATTACH THE NEW PDF THAT WAS SAVED ABOVE
$components['attachments'] .= array(FPDF_PATH .'/dompdf-master/'.'Shoop.pdf'); // ATTACH THE NEW PDF THAT WAS SAVED ABOVE
}
return $components;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Convert:

```
$components['attachments'] .= array(FPDF_PATH .'/dompdf-master/'.'Shoop.pdf');
```

To:

```
$components['attachments'][] = FPDF_PATH .'/dompdf-master/'.'Shoop.pdf';
```